# mageplaza and catalog search conflict in magento2

Tags: module, catalogsearch, magento2.3.2

I am using mageplaza plugin in magento 2.3.2. But in catalog search while searching with 2 character length it gives me error like you have processing error. I checked setting in admin panel there is setting like catalog search minimum query length is set to 3. If set this to 1 then it working fine. But on staging with all condition it is working fine. Please let me know the reason, this is happen?